# Use awk to replace a column without changing format

Tags: command-line, awk

I have a PDB file (see below) and I need to change the A in column 5 to a B, AND I need to change it without changing the format of the original file. I was able to change the A to a B using  this awk command:

```
$ awk '{sub(/A/,"B",$5); print;}' file 1 > file 2

ATOM      1  N   GLY A 302      77.282 -99.685 -10.078  1.00  0.00        N
ATOM      2  CA  GLY A 302      78.728 -99.868 -10.031  1.00  0.00        C
ATOM      3  C   GLY A 302      79.457 -98.600 -10.458  1.00  0.00        C
ATOM      4  O   GLY A 302      80.646 -98.435 -10.185  1.00  0.00        O
```

Comment: What are the delimiters? Are these letters on their own, or part of a string? Sample input and output would be helpful, as would showing us what you have tried...

Comment: I don't understand... is there a question here?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if ($5 == "A") gsub(/A/,"B",$5)}1' file > new_file
```

Answer (score -1):

I work a lot with PDB files. I think it would be easier to open the file in Vim, and then do `:%s/ A / B /g`